# Buying a car for temporary use outside of my home state?

Tags: vehicle, colorado, idaho

Strange scenario here: I live in Idaho, and would like to be in Colorado for a few weeks. Cars are cheaper in Colorado than Idaho (assume this is true).

I'd like to fly to Colorado, buy a car, use it there for a few weeks, and drive it back to Idaho. I don't have any immediate intent to sell the car on returning to Idaho.

Everything I can find about buying a car out of state assumes you're buying the car and immediately going back to your home state. This isn't what I want to do. I want to use the car in Colorado for a while first.

I'm happy to pay registration/tax/title/etc. fees in Idaho, but if I have to make a roundtrip just to visit the DMV once, that'd be kinda silly and I might as well buy the car before leaving.

I keep coming up short on finding out how to pull this off. I'd much appreciate any pointers ya'll have!

Comment: I mean, there's the obvious and not particularly pleasant one,  register it in when you buy it in Colorado then re-register when you "move" it to Idaho.  I think what you'd want to do is be able to say I'm an Idaho resident, can I register this car with Idaho stuff while physically you and the car are in Colorado...and that sounds like a question for the Idaho DMV?

Comment: @Alan I'd be fine with that, but I'm pretty sure you can't really register a car without being a resident of the same state. Or at least that's what I gather from there being a fairly short list of states where it *is* legal, e.g. on https://clearsurance.com/blog/can-i-register-a-car-in-a-different-state-than-i-live-in. Seems to me that this case is entirely unsupported by the system...

Answer (score 0):

Colorado law applies to Colorado citizens and requires licensing a car bought from a dealer within 60 days [Colorado DMV](https://dmv.colorado.gov/registration-requirements). Idaho law applies to Idaho residents and requires registering it in 30 days.  [Idaho DMV](https://itd.idaho.gov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/DMV_Vehicle-Titles.pdf).

So it looks like only the Idaho one would apply, and even if Colorado's would too, they would give you even more time.  So fly to Colorado,  buy a car from a dealer, have fun for a few weeks, then drive home and get it registered before 30 days is up and you should be all good.

Comment: Thank you, those are the links I needed. Seems like I shouldn't have an issue if I get stopped on the drive back, just show a recent bill of sale & title instead of a registration?

Comment: Yep,  and when you buy from a dealer they generate a temporary tag for you. @und